# Melting Dataframe with multi levels and specific Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have a dataframe with 2 levels that looks like this : [dataframe input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhzRW.png)

I would like to melt this dataframe so it would look like this : [dataframe desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtqdq.png)

I tried using melt but I am not able to make appear the columns "Mass" and "Energy".
I don't get how to use the options of the melt function. The function "reset_index" might help to ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `df.T.reset_index()`?

Comment: It does do the job ! Thank you for your help !!